# Classifying finite symmetry groups in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm working through Thomas Judson's online abstract algebra [textbook](http://abstract.ups.edu/aata/section-symmetry.html), and in chapter 12 he introduces isometries and symmetry groups, defining the latter as the subgroup of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that leave some $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ invariant. One thing that's confusing me is in his proof of the following theorem: "The only finite symmetry groups in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $D_n$."

In his proof, he starts by saying:

> We simply need to find all the finite subgroups $G$ of $E(2)$. Any finite symmetry group $G$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ must fix the origin and must be a finite subgroup of $O(2)$, since translations and glide reflections have infinite order.

He then proceeds to show that the only finite subgroups of $O(2)$ are $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $D_n$. I understand the remainder of the proof, but his claim that all finite symmetry groups must fix the origin doesn't make sense to me. For instance, the subgroup of $E(2)$ given by $G=\{(I,\mathbf{0}), (-I, 2\mathbf{\hat{x}})\}$ seems to me to be a symmetry group of $X = \{\mathbf{\hat{y}}+\mathbf{\hat{x}}, -\mathbf{\hat{y}}+\mathbf{\hat{x}}\}$, since $g(X)=X$ for all $g \in G$, yet it clearly doesn't fix the origin for all $g \in G$.

Now, in this case $G$ is simply $\mathbb{Z}_2$, so we haven't disproved the theorem. However, if we can no longer rule out groups whose elements don't fix the origin, then it no longer is clear to me how proving that the finite subgroups of $O(2)$ are $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $D_n$ is sufficient to prove the theorem at hand.

So, is my question is: **is my understanding of the definitions or my example flawed in some way? Or, if this statement given in the proof is false, how can we modify his proof to correctly prove the theorem?**

(Note: I am using the convention that if $g=(A,\mathbf{a})$, then $g(\mathbf{x}) = A\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{a}$).

Comment: $E(2)$ is the semidirect product of $O(2)$ by translations. A finite symmetry group cannot contain translations, which form an infinite subgroup. In your case $G$ is not a subgroup.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I was assuming that my $G$ not actually being a subgroup of $E(2)$ was a likely cause, but I've looked over it a bunch and I can't see how that's the case-- it clearly has the identity in it and $(-I,2\hat{\mathbf{x}})$ is its own inverse, which also takes care of closure: $(-I,2\hat{\mathbf{x}})^2=((-I)^2, -I(2\hat{\mathbf{x}}) + 2\hat{\mathbf{x}}) = (I, \mathbf{0})$. Where am I going wrong in my reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you demonstrated, not every finite subgroup $G$ of $E(2)$ fixes the origin, so on that point the book is incorrect. But there must be *some* point fixed by $G$, and you get an isomorphism of $G$ with a subgroup of $O(2)$ via conjugation by a translation.

Why must $G$ fix some point? The proof is actually interesting. Pick an arbitrary point $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and let
$$\mathbf{c} = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} g\mathbf{x}.$$
(Note that this only works because $G$ is finite!) Then $\mathbf{c}$ is fixed by all of $G$: For any $h \in G$, we have
$$h\mathbf{c} = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} hg\mathbf{x}
 = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g' \in G} g'\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{c},$$
where the first equality is because $h$ is affine, and the second is from the substitution $g = h^{-1}g'$.

Comment: That's a very neat proof, thanks for sharing it! I'm glad to see that I wasn't just making some obvious mistake with my reasoning.